# LINQ concat predicate OR

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, predicate

Hi  I'm  trying to concat  an  linq expression
Ex: I have an  `List<string[]>` where I need to read this on a loop
i need to  creat a query  like this

```
from table where (name ='someone' && id='123') || (name ='another one' && id='223') || ( name='noone' && id='456')
```

the follow code is what I'm working on

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var name= item[4];
    var cnpj = item[1];
    Expression<Func<IncidentIntegration, bool>> predicated = (x => (x.EmployeesBase.name== name && x.Branch.id== id));
    query = query.Union(query.Where(predicated));
 }
```

But it's creating a query  like this

```
from table where (name ='someone' || name ='another one' || name='noone') && ( id='223' || id='123' || id='456')
```

Is there someway to concat this ?

Comment: Can your `data` array's structure or sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach below. İt is simple and usable. Tou dont need to deal with dynamic expressions.

```
var result = list.Where(x => arr.Any(t => <your_condition>))
```

Comment: you do realize, that you do not actually use `x` or `arr` at all?

Comment: I tried this way, this is creating an "and" not "or" like  (name='a' && id='1') AND (name ='b' && id='2')

Comment: Sorry check my edit please

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it can help you

If we consider CompleteInfos as your table then :

```
public class CompleteInfos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
public class Info{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<CompleteInfos> Table = new List<CompleteInfos>(); 
// List contains your namse and ids
List<Info> infos = new List<Info>(){
        new Info(){Id = 123 , Name = "someone"},
        new Info(){Id = 223 , Name = "another"},
        new Info(){Id = 456 , Name = "noone"}
} 
foreach(var info in infos)
{
    List<CompleteInfos> selectedInfo = Table.Where(x => x.Id == info.Id || x.Name == info.Name).ToList();

    //selectedInfo  is the list in which you can find all item that have your desired id and name
}
```

Comment: Well one  of the reasons that  I'm not using toList is because I don't want  to  reach the database for each line, I  may  have more than  thousand itens so I'd like to make only one query, and I'm afraid that this may  heavy the connection

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons this procedure should not request the data base each time. for example you run a `SELECT` query on the database and then all data will be inside the RAM